# Transfer progress bar in another page in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, progress-bar

I have a Javascript function which shows the progress bar?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Counter = 10;
function DoCounter()
{
    SlideParent = document.getElementById("SliderParent");
    Slide = document.getElementById("Slider");
    Slide.style.width = Counter + "%";
    Slide.innerHTML = Counter + "%";
    if(Counter <25)
    {
        SlideParent.style.borderColor = "green";
        Slide.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    }
    else if(Counter >= 25 && Counter < 50)
    {
        SlideParent.style.borderColor = "blue";
        Slide.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    }
    else if(Counter >= 50 && Counter < 75)
    {
        SlideParent.style.borderColor = "orange";
        Slide.style.backgroundColor = "orange";
    }
    else
    {
        SlideParent.style.borderColor = "red";
        Slide.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
    if(Counter++ < 100)
    {
        setTimeout("DoCounter()",100);
    }
}

</script>
```

This is what I have inside body tag:

```
<div id="sync"><input type="submit" onclick="DoCounter();" /></div>
<div id="SliderParent" style="width:100%;">
    <div id="Slider" style="width:0%; border-width:0px; background-color:red; color:white">
        0%  
    </div>
</div>
```

When the user clicks submit the progress bar is loaded in the same page. I want the progress bar to load into the same page but my removing all the contents. `document.write("Uploading..Please Wait")` do so. I want to erase all the contents and add `Uploading ..Please Wait` with progress bar below. How can I do that?

Comment: **Never** pass a string to `setInterval()` or `setTimeout()`. Doing so is as bad as using `eval()` and it results in unreadable and possibly insecure code as soon as you use variables since you need to insert them into the string instead of passing the actual variable. The proper solution is `setInterval(function() { /* your code *) }, msecs);`. The same applies to `setTimeout()`. If you just want to call a single function without any arguments, you can also pass the function name directly: `setInterval(someFunction, msecs);` (note that there are **no** `()` behind the function name)

Comment: Thank you for the heads up. For now, how can I achieve my result? Thanks